# Android Motion Layout view should come from Right to Left

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I am new to motion layout. It is working in but not as expected.

What I want to achieve is that I have one input layout and next button on the screen and when we tap on the next button it should hide the input layout and show another view where the user can enter some field as shown in the below gif.

[image]

So the next section called remark to look like it is coming from top to bottom but I want it as it should come from the right side.

Here is my XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/content_padding"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/v2v_motionscene">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipientEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{email}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="demo@gmail.com" />


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/noteInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            android:hint="Remark"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="helperTextView, money_input"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amountView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/transferAmountHeight"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@{amount}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline4"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            tools:text="$0.00"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helperTextView"
            goneWhen="@{helperText == null}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@{helperText}"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceCaption"
            android:textColor="@color/color_error"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountView"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <com.varomoney.bank.presentation.view.MoneyInput
            android:id="@+id/money_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/helperTextView"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            layout="@layout/epoxy_action_row"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is my motionsense file:

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/starting_set"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/ending_set"
        motion:duration="500">

        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragRight" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/starting_set">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/amountView"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipientEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/transferAmountHeight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/content_padding"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="34sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/noteInputLayout"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/ending_set">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/amountView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recipientEmail"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
            android:textSize="28sp">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/money_input"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/helperTextView"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/noteInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button_next"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recipientEmail"
            android:visibility="visible">
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Am I missing something? or how should I achieve this?

Comment: Can you try to set the `noteInputLayout` constraints in the `starting_set` all to bottom rigth?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @cutiko, thank you, it worked. I haven't added to bottom right but as per requirement I have added the  starting_set and it worked. :)